# Handling Error With a Function Which Returns a Object

Tags: c++, error-handling, return-type

I want to output a message/error onto the console when a condition isn't met, but the function returns a object. What is a good way of handling this problem?

```
Person PriorityQueue::poll()
{
    if (size == 0)
    {
        std::cout << "\nERROR: Empty Queue\n";
        //How Do I Return From Here
    }

    if (size == 1)
    {
        end--;
        size--;
        return queue[(end + 1)];
    }
    else if (size > 1)
    {
        Person temp = queue[0];
        queue[0] = queue[end];
        end--;
        size--;

        bubbleDown(0);

        return temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did You consider throwing an exception?

Answer (score 0):

You can use exceptions. However exceptions are frequently abused, there are other alternatives (like a return value, `std::optional`, `std::tuple`, `shared_ptr`). 
Generally I avoid returning a value that must have a meaning (like a constructed object) because there should be a way to check an error condition.